# Does c# have a collection that works like a cache?

Tags: c#, caching

Looking for a dictionary or similar that automatically removes entries after a specific amount of time, either if they're not used for X amount of time, or simply removed after X amount of time regardless of use.

Before I roll my own I was wondering if C# already has this capability in one of its collections. I haven't seen anything on google but I wanted to check.

Comment: You're looking for [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Not sure why the downvote. You could put it into an answer or I can just delete the question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find [`MemoryCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) from `System.Runtime.Caching`. Although it isn't generic (if you're using value types, this may be something to consider), it has the TTL mechanism you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) - for .NET Framework applications.

[System.Web.Caching.Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx) - for ASP.NET applications.